# HyperParameterTuning job failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, data-science, amazon-sagemaker

why i get this error while auto tuning my xgboost algorithm,in amazon sagemaker"Error for HyperParameterTuning job sagemaker-xgboost-220217-0532: Failed. Reason: All training jobs failed. Please take a look at the training jobs failures to get more details."

Answer (score 0):

Please open a AWS support case with more details such as Job ARN, etc., and the support team will take a look.